# Restore PostgreSQL database with same locale settings as source database

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have a PostreSQL 9.x database on an *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* production machine.
My development machine is *Windows 7*-based, providing PostreSQL 9.y.

I want to restore the Ubuntu PostreSQL database on my development machine.

I noticed that the Ubuntu database uses the following locale settings:

- *character set encoding*=`UTF8`
- *collation order, string sort order*=`en_US.UTF-8`
- *character type, character classification*=`en_US.UTF-8`

When I restore the database on the Windows machine without specifying locales, it will be set up with

- *character set encoding*=`UTF8`
- *collation order, string sort order*=`German_Germany.1252`
- *character type, character classification*=`German_Germany.1252`

My plan is to have the database on my development machine as similar as possible to the database on my Ubuntu machine. So my idea was to first create a database on my Windows machine with production-matching locales, then restore my Ubuntu database `prod-db.backup` backup file into that created database:

```
createdb --host=localhost --username=postgres --encoding=Unicode --lc-collate=en_US.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_US.UTF-8 --owner=prod prod-db
pg_restore --host=localhost --username=postgres --format=custom prod-db.backup --dbname=prod-db
```

This ideas does not work as the `createdb` on Windows will complain with the error *invalid locale name en_US.UTF-8*.

I went on a hunt to find the [Windows locale names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5152866/923560) that match the Ubuntu locale names, including [a solution to use the *template0* template database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956778/923560), experimenting with different locale identifiers such as `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_us_utf8` I found scattered in the Internet ... but no solution works.

- Is there a locale identifier for Windows that matches Ubuntu's `en_US.UTF-8`?
- Or is locale `German_Germany.1252` identical (enough) to `en_US.UTF-8` so that I can stick to it and not worry about locales - I want to make sure that database queries behave identical when it comes to aspects such as query result set ordering.

Comment: Just create db with --encoding=UTF8. After that run an ordinary restore. Finally change your client connection parameters. Ref: [Locale and Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html)

Comment: @SahapAsci But client connections won't change the database's configured locales, right?

Comment: no, for sure. encoding is utf8. that means your saved strings will be always the same. lc_* settings are for display formats and orderings and actually its for client. if you set it from server side and a client connect without providing any lc_* settings then it will take the default, server provided ones.

Answer (score 5):

These are the exact steps I take to import a copy of a PostgreSQL 9.5 database (exported on Linux using `en_US.UTF-8` encoding) into PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows 7 or PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows 8.1. You need to create the database with the appropriate encoding prior to loading the SQL file, otherwise the encoding from Linux (`en_US.UTF-8`) will prompt Windows to use a default encoding.

```
REM WARNING: Console code page (65001) differs from Windows code page (1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
chcp 1252

C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe -U postgres -d postgres_password -c "CREATE DATABASE my_db WITH TEMPLATE=template0 ENCODING='UTF-8' LC_COLLATE='american_usa' LC_CTYPE='american_usa'"

REM Grant privileges to the appropriate database user.
C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe -U postgres -d postgres_password -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO myuser"

REM Import my_db.sql. Ignore the following error (it comes from a line in the SQL file, but we have already created the database with the correct locale, so we are ok):
REM psql:my_db.sql:22: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.UTF-8"

C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe -o nul --quiet -U postgres -d postgres_password -f my_db.sql
```

As discussed [here](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2011/02/27/locale-windows/), the locale on Windows should be `american_usa` (on Windows 7). On Windows 8.1, either `american_usa` or `en-US` (not `en_US` as with Unix) will work.

Comment: This really works.